# Canvas getImageData is always the same for 2 visually different images

Tags: javascript, canvas, sha256

I've got 3 images, 2 are visually identical but they have different file names and one is completely different. I load the images, put them on a canvas, get the image data and compare the image.

The 2 that are visually the same returns true which is correct
when comparing 2 that are not visually the same it also returns true which is not correct.

**UPDATED from @obscure answer below**

```js
window.onload = function () {
setTimeout(process, 5000);
};

async function process() {
  const img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  const img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
  const img3 = document.getElementById("img3");

  img1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img3.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

  const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  canvas1.width = img1.width;
  canvas1.height = img1.height;
  ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  const pixData1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, img1.width, img1.height).data;

  const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  canvas2.width = img2.width;
  canvas2.height = img2.height;
  ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
  const pixData2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, img2.width, img2.height).data;

  const canvas3 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
  canvas3.width = img3.width;
  canvas3.height = img3.height;
  ctx3.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);
  const pixData3 = ctx3.getImageData(0, 0, img3.width, img3.height).data;

  const utf8A = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData1.toString());
  let img1Hash = await crypto.subtle
.digest("SHA-256", utf8A)
.then((hashBuffer) => {
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
});

  const utf8B = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData2.toString());
  let img2Hash = await crypto.subtle
.digest("SHA-256", utf8B)
.then((hashBuffer) => {
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
});

  const utf8C = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData3.toString());
  let img3Hash = await crypto.subtle
.digest("SHA-256", utf8C)
.then((hashBuffer) => {
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
});

  console.log(img1Hash);
  console.log(img2Hash);
  console.log(img3Hash);

  console.log(img1Hash === img2Hash);
  console.log(img1Hash === img3Hash); // Should be false
  console.log(img2Hash === img3Hash); // Should be false
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg" id="img1" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg" id="img2" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/QdqhGb9.jpg" id="img3" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two different arrays in JavaScript will never compare as equal. You'll have to write code to to a character-by-character comparison.

Comment: could I SHA258 the arrays then compare the hashes? Or convert the arrays to strings then compare them?

Comment: Yes you could do that, or encode them as base64 strings.

Comment: @Bill is your question answered now or do you need help with hashing jpegs?

Comment: any help on how to create hashes from `getImageData` that will only compare the visual aspects of an image would be much appreciated. `crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", utf8)` says the images are diferent

Comment: Did you execute subtle.digest on the `Uint8ClampedArray` contained in the .data property (returns 3755862355e2e7d0e0dc0f6b98a89978c0710890982862dd17975829e35be6b4 for both images here)?

Comment: Note that this may be an error only in the code you posted, but you call `getImageData()` on `ctx1` both times.

Comment: @obscure like `crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", pixData1.data).then...` ??

Comment: Are only the files'names difderent? I.E, are the actual images the same? In that case, the pixels that are drawn on the canvas will be the same, the original file name has no incidence whatsoever on what is drawn.

Comment: @Bill If you have two images of same size why not just check if they have same pixel colors? You can use a For-loop to check if pixel values are matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare two array for equality you can indeed use a hashing algorithm. Utilizing `crypto.subtle` is an easy solution but I'm afraid you aren't aware what the `.digest()` method does/returns.

From your code it seems you think it's a synchronous operation:

```
  let img1Hash = "";
  const utf8A = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData1.toString());
  crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", utf8A).then((hashBuffer) => {
    img1Hash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
  });
  console.log(img1Hash); // nothing logged
```

Well it's an asynchronous operation and `digest()` returns a promise. So if you simply log `img1Hash` after calling digest() will be an empty string as the promise didn't fulfill yet. Likewise a comparison like `img1Hash === img2Hash` will yield true as both variables contain empty strings at that point in time.

So you need to wait until both promises are resolved. This can be done by wrapping your whole onload code block inside an async function `process()` and `await` the results of calling `digest()`. Unfortunately this would still not return true if you do a comparison because you make the result an array again:

```
Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer))
```

If you convert it to a String you can compare it for equality.

Here's the complete code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  process();


};

async function process() {
  const img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  const img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

  img1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

  const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  canvas1.width = img1.width;
  canvas1.height = img1.height;
  ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  const pixData1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, img1.width, img1.height).data;

  const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  canvas2.width = img2.width;
  canvas2.height = img2.height;
  ctx2.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
  const pixData2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, img2.width, img2.height).data;


  const utf8A = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData1.toString());
  let img1Hash = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", utf8A).then((hashBuffer) => {
    return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
  });


  const utf8B = new TextEncoder().encode(pixData2.toString());
  let img2Hash = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", utf8B).then((hashBuffer) => {
    return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
  });



  console.log(img1Hash); // nothing logged
  console.log(img2Hash); // nothing logged
  console.log(img1Hash === img2Hash); // true

}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg" id="img1" />
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg" id="img2" />
```

## Edit

As you're struggling to get the correct hashes for each of your images, let's do things a bit different. Instead of referencing a real html `<img>` element, let's create those dynamically and add 'em to the DOM if ready.

So the following snippet:

```js
let sources = ['https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/QdqhGb9.jpg'];
let images = [];
let imageData = [];
let hashes = [];
let counter = 0;

function loaded(e) {
  counter++;
  if (counter == 3) {
    process();
  }
}

async function process() {
  let utf8;
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = images[0].width;
  canvas.height = images[0].height;
  for (let a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {
    ctx.drawImage(images[a], 0, 0);
    imageData.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data);

    utf8 = new TextEncoder().encode(imageData[a].toString());
    hashes.push(await crypto.subtle
      .digest("SHA-256", utf8)
      .then((hashBuffer) => {
        return Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)).toString();
      }));
  }

  console.log(hashes[0]);
  console.log(hashes[1]);
  console.log(hashes[2]);
}



let img;
for (let a = 0; a < sources.length; a++) {
  img = new Image();
  images.push(img);
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.onload = loaded;
  img.src = sources[a];
}
```

returns three unique, completely different hashes.

```
100,172,184,128,122,59,32,239,211,133,243,51,25,159,237,239,175,140,198,232,133,184,77,224,174,85,38,1,164,52,30,68
88,209,142,171,42,213,152,27,60,14,200,193,162,134,50,183,110,70,166,231,237,163,215,129,184,249,106,41,16,147,151,97
72,2,137,13,168,131,212,29,170,19,57,24,39,91,164,32,38,2,170,231,124,72,78,64,168,135,84,1,108,11,161,216
```

As you've surely guessed by now using hashes for comparing two images visually isn't the way to go. What you could do instead is compare image A's color at x, y with image B's at the same position and sum up the differences. If the total difference is within a certain threshold the images should be considered equal.

To do this we need to convert the RGB colors to the HSV color model, as it's better suited for a 'human' color comparison.

```js
let sources = ['https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/QdqhGb9.jpg'];
let images = [];
let imageData = [];
let hashes = [];
let counter = 0;

function loaded(e) {
  counter++;
  if (counter == 3) {
    process();
  }
}

async function process() {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = images[0].width;
  canvas.height = images[0].height;
  for (let a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {
    ctx.drawImage(images[a], 0, 0);
    imageData.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data);
  }

  compare(imageData[0], imageData[1]);
  compare(imageData[0], imageData[2]);
}

function compare(imgDataA, imgDataB) {
  let hslA, hslB, avgH, avgS, avgL, difference;
  let differences = 0;
  let counter = 0;
  for (let a = 0; a < imgDataA.length; a += 4) {
    hslA = rgbToHsl(imgDataA[a], imgDataA[a + 1], imgDataA[a + 2]);
    hslB = rgbToHsl(imgDataB[a], imgDataB[a + 1], imgDataB[a + 2]);
    avgH = (hslA[0] + hslB[0]) / 2;
    avgS = (hslA[1] + hslB[1]) / 2;
    avgL = (hslA[2] + hslB[2]) / 2;
    differences += (Math.abs(hslA[0] - avgH) + Math.abs(hslA[1] - avgS) + Math.abs(hslA[2] - avgL)) / 3;

    counter++;
  }
  console.log(differences / (imgDataA.length / 4));
}

let img;
for (let a = 0; a < sources.length; a++) {
  img = new Image();
  images.push(img);
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.onload = loaded;
  img.src = sources[a];
}

// taken from: https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256#file-color-conversion-algorithms-js
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;

  var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0;
  } else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);

    switch (max) {
      case r:
        h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
        break;
      case g:
        h = (b - r) / d + 2;
        break;
      case b:
        h = (r - g) / d + 4;
        break;
    }

    h /= 6;
  }

  return [h, s, l];
}
```

As a side note: The `rgbToHsl()` function above was taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256). If you run the example you get a difference of `0.012553120747668494` between the first and the second and `0.02681219030137108` for the first and the third image. So one could determine that images are equal if it's difference is less than or equal `0.018` for example.

Comment: That's a massive help, I can't thank you enough, If I compare image 1 and 3 it still says they are the same though, any idea?

Comment: That has probably to do with the window.onload event you're using. The 2/3 images aren't loaded yet so your canvases are just empty. You can listen for the onload event for the individual images and if all are fully loaded execute process(). By the way, this won't return an equal hash for img1 and img2 though as those are really just equal for the human eye thus the hashing algorithm will return something completely different. The hash will just be equal if it's indeed the same file.

Comment: I added a 5-second timeout to give the images time to load and it still returns an equal hash for images 1 2 and 3

Comment: Maybe my updated answer will help you on your journey!